# NGINX Rewrite single HTTPS URL to HTTP

Tags: nginx

On my NGINX server, I have all non-SSL traffic redirected to my SSL site.

Now, I want to have a single URL excluded from this, specifically:
**https**://pyronexus.com/forum/pages.php and everything appended to pages.php, such as pages.php?page=blahblah redirected to **http**://pyronexus.com/forum/pages.php, etc.

My config file looks like this so far, but I've not had any luck in getting my rewrite for this single url to work.

```
server {
    server_name
        www.pyronexus.com
    ;

    listen 80 default;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate ssl/pyronexus.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/pyronexus.com.key;

    return 301 https://pyronexus.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name
        pyronexus.com
    ;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 default ssl;

    ssl_certificate ssl/pyronexus.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/pyronexus.com.key;

    root /home/nginx/pyronexus.com/public;
    index index.html index.php;

    access_log /home/nginx/pyronexus.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/nginx/pyronexus.com/logs/error.log;

    include php.conf;
    include mime.types;

    location /forum/ {
        #include pyronexus-naxsi.rules;
        rewrite ^/forum/forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost;
        rewrite ^/forum/thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2;
        rewrite ^/forum/post-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/showthread.php?pid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/announcements.php?aid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/user-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/member.php?action=profile&uid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/calendar.php?calendar=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/calendar.php?action=yearview&calendar=$1&year=$2;
        rewrite ^/forum/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3;
        rewrite ^/forum/calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4;
        rewrite ^/forum/calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2;
        rewrite ^/forum/event-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1;
        rewrite ^/forum/archive/index\.php/forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/archive/index.php?forum-$1.html;
        rewrite ^/forum/archive/index\.php/thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/archive/index.php?thread-$1.html;
    }

    location ~ /forum/(inc) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The rewrite rule I have tried is this, but I'm still getting to grips on how these rules work:

```
rewrite ^https://pyronexus.com/forum/pages\.php(.*)$ http://pyronexus.com/forum/pages.php$1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open up the configuration for your site, mine is /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pyronexus.com.
   Add the following server directive, adjusting the variables as needed:

   ```
   server {
       server_name
           www.your-site.com
       ;

       listen 80;
       listen 443 ssl;

       ssl_certificate ssl/your-certificate.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key ssl/your-certificate.key;

       return 301 https://your-site.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```

   This directive will force any www connections, be it through SSL or non-SSL, to non-www.
2. Add another directive. Although in this directive you can add any exclusions of pages you don’t want to be SSL-enabled. Add them before the location ~ / {} directive (I’ve included an example in there, which excludes http://your-site.com/forum/pages.php from HTTPS connections):

   ```
   server {
       server_name
           your-site.com
       ;

       listen 80 default;

       root /your/site/root;

       access_log /your/logs/location/access.log;
       error_log /your/logs/location/error.log;

       include global.conf;

       # This excludes forum/pages.php from being forced through HTTPS
       location ~ ^/forum/pages\.php$ {
           include php.conf;
       }

       # This will force any http:// connections through https://
       location ~ / {
           return 301 https://your-site.com$request_uri;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add a third, and final directive. This one is the directive that handles all SSL connections. You’ll need to put any exclusions you put above in here as well, and redirect people to a http connection:

   ```
   server {
       server_name
           your-site.com
       ;

       listen 443 default ssl;

       ssl_certificate ssl/your-site.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key ssl/your-site.key;

       root /your/site/root;

       access_log /your/logs/location/access.log;
       error_log /your/logs/location/error.log;

       include global.conf;

       # This will force forum/pages.php through http://
       location ~ ^/forum/pages\.php$ {
           return 301 http://your-site.com$request_uri;
       }

       include php.conf;
   }
   ```

That’s it! Test your configuration out!

If you’re wondering what’s in my global.conf and php.conf, then here they are:

global.conf:

```
# Tries to access the file directly before handing over to index.php
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Exclude common static file formats from logging and cache as long as possible
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|txt)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires max;
}

# Deny access to files that start with a dot, such as .htaccess
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

# Deny access to php files in folders named uploads and files (this is to prevent people uploading php files and executing them)
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

php.conf:

```
# Pass all php files to php5-fpm
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Source: https://pyronexus.com/blog/2015/01/11/nginx-remove-www-and-force-ssl-connections/